# Is it possible to have file filters for multiple extension types?

Tags: windows, c++-cli, openfiledialog

I'm using a standard Windows FileDialog to allow the user to select some files. I'd like to [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx) out only the file types I'm interested in though (lets call them `*.a` and `*.b`). Is there any way to do this without using `*.*`? I've tried the following but it fails to match any files at all:

```
this->openFileDialog1->DefaultExt = L"*.a,*.b";
this->openFileDialog1->FileName = L"openFileDialog1";
this->openFileDialog1->Filter = L"My Data Files (*.a,*.b)|*.a,*.b";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a semicolon:

```
this->openFileDialog1->Filter = L"My Data Files (*.a;*.b)|*.a;*.b";
```